# app-engine server to retrieve image from blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, blobstore, google-cloud-endpoints

In the following snippets, is `resource` the blob key?

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                               ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                               ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

And if I wanted to call the blobstore from the server (as oppose to having an external caller call to `ServeHandler`), how would I do that? Basically I want my backend to retrieve the blob_key (from my datastore) and then get the image from the blob_store (or is there another way for the backend to retrieve an image from the blobstore?).

link to google tutorial: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the resource is the blob_key.  See the [BlobInfo](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass#BlobInfo_get) documentation on get.

You can read from the BlobStore directly via the [BlobReader class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Do you know how I would read the blob into a variable so I could send it through `endpoints.method` using `messages.BytesField`? I mean, in `value = blob_reader.read()` can I just send `value` as the `messages.BytesField`?